# How to reuse Karabiner rule?

Tags: karabiner

I have the following rule:

```
    {
      "description": "Cmd+Opt+7 ↦ {space≔7, Cmd+Opt+7}",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "keypad_7",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "command",
                "option"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "set_variable": {
                "name": "space",
                "value": 7
              }
            },
            {
              "key_code": "keypad_7",
              "modifiers": [
                "command",
                "option"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```

and I would like the following rule to call the above so it decreases duplicated code (ie the part about setting the variable and maybe even the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> part):

```
    {
      "description": "space≡8 ⋀ Cmd+Opt+Left ↦ {space≔7, Cmd+Opt+7}",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "left_arrow",
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "command",
                "option"
              ],
              "optional": [
                "caps_lock"
              ]
            }
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "set_variable": {
                "name": "space",
                "value": 7
              }
            },
            {
              "key_code": "keypad_7",
              "modifiers": [
                "command",
                "option"
              ]
            }
          ],
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "variable_if",
              "name": "space",
              "value": 8
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Is there a way to extract duplicated code in Karabiner so it can be reused?